# <link rel=preload> uses an unsupported `as` value when using audio

Tags: html, browser, html5-audio

I'm trying to preload an audio asset like so:

`<link rel="preload" href="/assets/letters/c.wav" as="audio"/>`

All browsers effectively say the same thing: " uses an unsupported `as` value" and don't preload the resource.

I can "trick" Chrome into downloading the resource by using "script" as the value but this doesn't work on Safari or Firefox.

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload#what_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded), audio is a valid asset for preload. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue. Chrome might simply be inconsistent with the HTML specification here.

As a workaround, you can preload audio simply by embedding audio elements on the page without playing them, e.g.,

```html
<audio src="/assets/letters/c.wav" />
```